# Interpolation with interpolate.splrep

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

Good afternoon, I want to change the green lines in splines here:
[image]
So, I wrote this :

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

x=np.array([-1.51680376, -5.59528478,  3.02763056,  3.99336847,  
1.16267044,2.76931318, -0.07837944,  2.16852768, -1.81093278,  
1.82262034,-5.47060927,  1.49435114, -7.97536149,  1.05175547, 
-4.12788774,0.31526786, -4.4241668 ])

y=np.array([45,45,41.1314913,41,40.25582197,40,39.33855863,39,
38.45406219,38,37.69804062,37,37,36,36,35,35])

tck = interpolate.splrep(x, y)
xnew = np.arange(min(x),max(x), 200)
ynew = interpolate.splev(xnew, tck)

plt.plot(x,y,'g',xnew,ynew)  
plt.show()
```

I have a problem in this line:

```
f48=interpolate.splrep(x,y)
```

Python says there is an error on input data but I don't understand why...

Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that argument `x` in the call to `splrep()` is not sorted and it must be sorted. `splrep()`, according to the documentation, relies on `curfit` Fortran routine from `FITPACK`. See https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/fitpack/curfit.f for the code of `curfit`.

According to comments in the `curfit.f`:

```
c    ier=10 : error. on entry, the input data are controlled on validity
c             the following restrictions must be satisfied.
c             -1<=iopt<=1, 1<=k<=5, m>k, nest>2*k+2, w(i)>0,i=1,2,...,m
c             xb<=x(1)<x(2)<...<x(m)<=xe, lwrk>=(k+1)*m+nest*(7+3*k)
c             if iopt=-1: 2*k+2<=n<=min(nest,m+k+1)
c                         xb<t(k+2)<t(k+3)<...<t(n-k-1)<xe
c                       the schoenberg-whitney conditions, i.e. there
c                       must be a subset of data points xx(j) such that
c                         t(j) < xx(j) < t(j+k+1), j=1,2,...,n-k-1
c             if iopt>=0: s>=0
c                         if s=0 : nest >= m+k+1
c             if one of these conditions is found to be violated,control
c             is immediately repassed to the calling program. in that
c             case there is no approximation returned.
```

that is, `x(1)<x(2)<x(3)...`. For your data this condition is not satisfied. Moreover, `y(x)` is a multi-valued function.

Instead, I think you should try fitting `x` vs. `y` and to keep `y` sorted - reverse it:

```
f48=interpolate.splrep(y[::-1], x[::-1])
```